# Retrieve the current unique URL of a firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-oauth, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a firebase cloud function to authenticate user and obtains refresh_token and access_token for later use. Here is the snippet to initialize Google OAuth2 client:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

module.exports = () => new google.auth.OAuth2(
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  `${BACKEND_URL}/authCallback`,
);
```

Currently I have to deploy the function to firebase first before I can get the value for `BACKEND_URL`. Is there away I can retrieve the current firebase unique URL inside the function?

Answer (score 6):

HTTPS function urls look like this:

```
https://us-central1-YOUR-PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/test
```

where "us-central1" is the region of deployment, and "YOUR-PROJECT" is the name of your Firebase/Cloud project.  "test" is the name of the function.  Everything else stays the same.

`process.env.FUNCTION_REGION` is the region where the current function has been deployed.

`process.env.GCP_PROJECT` is the name of the project where the current function has been deployed.

So, you can build the URL using the contents of those two process environment variables, if you are assuming that the currently running function shares the same project and deployment region as the target HTTPS function.

Comment: Hey, Doug! The things have changed since you answered the question. The new Node.js v10 runtime doesn't have FUNCTION_REGION anymore: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_10_and_subsequent_runtimes

What's the updated approach to the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For the NodeJS v10 runtime the following works for http functions:

```js
export const yourFunction = functions.https.onRequest(((req, resp) => {
    const url = `https://${req.header('host')}/${process.env.FUNCTION_TARGET}${req.originalUrl}`;
    resp.send({url: url});
}))
```

You might skip `req.originalUrl` if you don't care about additionl path/query params.